# Objective-C : Sorting NSMutableArray containing NSMutableArrays

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I'm currently using `NSMutableArrays` in my developments to store some data taken from an HTTP Servlet.

Everything is fine since now I have to sort what is in my array.

This is what I do :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil] retain];
[array addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: "Label 1", 1, nil]];
[array addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: "Label 2", 4, nil]];
[array addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: "Label 3", 2, nil]];
[array addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: "Label 4", 6, nil]];
[array addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: "Label 5", 0, nil]];
```

First column contain a Label and 2nd one is a score I want the array to be sorted descending.

Is the way I am storing my data a good one ? Is there a better way to do this than using `NSMutableArrays` in `NSMutableArray` ?

I'm new to iPhone dev, I've seen some code about sorting but didn't feel good with that.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: This isn't an error per se, but it's not good style to say `[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil] retain]`.  Instead you should just use `[NSMutableArray initWithObjects:nil]`.

Comment: Actually, you should just use `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`.

Comment: Or `[NSMutableArray array]`.

Comment: (I wasn't aware that you could insert ints into an array.  Is this a new feature?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be much easier if you were to create a custom object (or at least use an `NSDictionary`) to store the information, instead of using an array.

For example:

```
//ScoreRecord.h
@interface ScoreRecord : NSObject {
  NSString * label;
  NSUInteger score;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * label;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger score;
@end

//ScoreRecord.m
#import "ScoreRecord.h"
@implementation ScoreRecord 
@synthesize label, score;

- (void) dealloc {
  [label release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end

//elsewhere:
NSMutableArray * scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ScoreRecord * first = [[ScoreRecord alloc] init];
[first setLabel:@"Label 1"];
[first setScore:1];
[scores addObject:first];
[first release];
//...etc for the rest of your scores
```

Once you've populated your `scores` array, you can now do:

```
//the "key" is the *name* of the @property as a string.  So you can also sort by @"label" if you'd like
NSSortDescriptor * sortByScore = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"score" ascending:YES];
[scores sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByScore]];
```

After this, your `scores` array will be sorted by the score ascending.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

I created my own object, it is very easier than before to sort my data.

Why do you use NSUInteger instead of simple int ?

Comment: @Dough `NSUInteger` will be 32 or 64 bit, depending on what platform it's running on.  `int` will always be 32 bits, and are the preferred and recommended way of using integers.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to create a custom class for something so trivial, it's a waste of code. You should use an array of `NSDictionary`'s (dictionary in ObjC = hash in other languages).

Do it like this:

```
  NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"my_label"],
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2" forKey:@"my_label"],
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"3" forKey:@"my_label"],
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"4" forKey:@"my_label"],
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"5" forKey:@"my_label"],
                            nil];
  NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"my_label" ascending:YES] autorelease];
  [array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer !

I prefer to use my own object in my case, but I think this can be a good one too :D