# How to sort 2d multidimensional NSMutablearray

Tags: xcode, cocoa, sorting, nsmutablearray, multidimensional-array

First i want to say sorry about my bad english. I hope you will unterstand.

i searched over three days for my problem and I found no solution :(
i have a NSMutablearray containing NSMutablearrays.

I get the data from the web. The weboutput looks like:

> ( ("Restaurant2" , "10" , "Hotel" , "Solitudestr" , "Germany" ,
>   "48.81155" , "9.10903"),("Club 2" , "14" , "Club" , "Weilimdorfer213"
>   , "Germany" , "48.814" , "9.1311666666667"),("Thai Meat" , "22" ,
>   "Gastro" , "Weilimdorfer193" , " 70469 Stuttgart" , "48.813833333333"
>   , "9.1328333333333") )

So I have here 3 NSMutablearray's inside one NSMutablearray. I am showing the Array at my Tableview with a custom cellview.

My question is how can I sort the three inner arrays with first Value.
(Values of first Value: Restaurant2,Club 2,Thai Meat)

So the first array should be:

> ("Club 2" , "14" , "Club" , "Weilimdorfer213" , "Germany" , "48.814" ,
>   "9.1311666666667")

second:

> ("Restaurant2" , "10" , "Hotel" , "Solitudestr" , "Germany" ,
>   "48.81155" , "9.10903")

third:

> ("Thai Meat" , "22" , "Gastro" , "Weilimdorfer193" , " 70469
>   Stuttgart" , "48.813833333333" , "9.1328333333333")

Which sortfunction should I use and how?

In the second step I want to get the distance of the given coordinates and sort the distance to the current position.

I got the distance, already. But how to sort this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to sort on string length of first value or something else?

Comment: I want to sort it alphabetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier if you were to create a custom object to store the information, instead of using an array.

Take a look at this example written by [Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766994/objective-c-sorting-nsmutablearray-containing-nsmutablearrays) post.

```
//ScoreRecord.h
@interface ScoreRecord : NSObject {
  NSString * label;
  NSUInteger score;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * label;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger score;
@end

//ScoreRecord.m
#import "ScoreRecord.h"
@implementation ScoreRecord 
@synthesize label, score;

- (void) dealloc {
  [score release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end

//elsewhere:
NSMutableArray * scores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ScoreRecord * first = [[ScoreRecord alloc] init];
[first setLabel:@"Label 1"];
[first setScore:1];
[scores addObject:first];
[first release];
//...etc for the rest of your scores
```

Once you've populated your `scores` array, you can now do:

```
//the "key" is the *name* of the @property as a string.  So you can also sort by @"label" if you'd like
NSSortDescriptor * sortByScore = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"score" ascending:YES];
[scores sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByScore]];
```

After this, your `scores` array will be sorted by the score ascending.

Take a look at [Collections Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) and [NSSortDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).